# A question about trace class operatos and partial isomertry

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, isometry

I'm a beginner in operator theory and I'm trying to understand just one step in a proof,which claims that if $H$ is a Hilbert space, $A\in B_1(H)$(that is , $A$ is a trace-class operator), and $U$ is a partial isometry such that $UA=|A|$, then $A=U^*UA=U^*|A|$. I have tried to prove the equation "$A=U^*UA$" but all my attempts have failed.

For example, I can prove that $U^*U$ is the projection onto the initial sapce. And I have tried to set $z:=U^*UA-A$ and   attempted to prove that $z^*z=0$. But I still can't prove the equation $A=U^*UA$.

Can anyone help? And sorry for the language barrier.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Trace class operators. In general if you have $A\in B(H)$ then there exists a partial isometry $U$ such that $A=U|A|$ and $|A|=U^*A$.

Comment: @NewB：If $A\in B(H)$ and U is a partial isometry, then how does one prove that $A=U*UA$?  Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're done if you can show that the range of $A$ is in the initial space of $U$. Based on the first condition in the proof [here](https://planetmath.org/partialisometryonhilbertspaces), it's sufficient to show for any $x, y$ that $\langle UAx, UAy\rangle = \langle Ax, Ay \rangle$.

We have: \begin{align*}
\langle UAx, UAy \rangle &= \langle |A|x, |A|y \rangle \\
&= \langle |A|^2x, y \rangle \\
&= \langle A^* A x, y \rangle \\
&= \langle Ax, Ay \rangle \\
\end{align*}

So the initial space of $U$ contains the range of $A$.  You're right that $P = U^*U$ is the projection onto $U$'s initial space, but it's critical that this space necessarily includes the range of $A$, which is why $PA = A$.

You can in general take $U$'s initial space to be exactly the (closure of the) range of $A$.

Comment: Sorry - I actually included the wrong link anyway!  I didn't mean to link to wikipedia.  See if the new link works.  If not, it's just the fact that $M$ is in the initial space of $W$ if $\langle Wf, Wg \rangle = \langle f, g \rangle$ for all $f, g \in M$.

Comment: This link works! Could you explain why we have $<|A|x,|A|y>=<|A|^2x,y>$ then?

Comment: In general, $\langle f, Tg \rangle = \langle T^* f, g \rangle$ by the definition of the adjoint.  I'm applying this to move the right $|A|$ over to the left side, noting that $|A|$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: Thanks. Now if I wish to prove the equation $UU^*|A|=|A|$, then it's sufficient to show that $R(|A|)$ is contained in $R(U)$ (as $UU^*$ is the projection onto $R(U)$). Is there any similar way to prove this? Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: I suppose you could try a similar approach to prove that equation, but if you’ve already established that $U^*|A|= A$ (as in the prompt), then just apply U to both sides to get $UU^*|A| = UA = |A|$.

Answer (score 3):

If $P$ is any (self-adjoint) projection then $\langle Px, x\rangle = \langle P^2 x, x\rangle = \langle P^* P x, x\rangle = \langle Px, Px \rangle = \|Px\|^2$.

$U^* U$ is a projection on the initial space and $(I-U^*U)$ a projection on the orthogonal complement of the initial space.  So $\|(I-U^* U)Ax\|^2 = \langle (I-U^*U)Ax, Ax \rangle = \langle A^*(I-U^*U)Ax, x\rangle$.

But $$\begin{align}A^*(I-U^*U)A &= A^*A - A^* U^* UA = A^* A - (UA)^* UA \\&= A^* A - |A|^* |A|= A^* A - |A|^2 = 0\end{align}$$
(since $UA = |A|$ by assumption.)

Combining we get $\|(I-U^* U)Ax\|^2 = 0$ for all $x$.  So $0=(I-U^*U)A = A - U^*U A\implies A = U^*UA$.

Comment: Could you explain why the equality "$A^*A-(UA)^*UA=A^*A-|A|^2$" holds? Since $UA=|A|$, $(UA)^*UA=|UA|^2=||A||^2$. Are you indicating that $||A||^2=|A|^2$?

Comment: $UA=|A|$ by assumption.  $|A|$ is not $\|A\|$.  $|A|$ is an operator.  $\|A\|$ is a number.  The definition of $|A|$ is the positive semi-definite square root of $A^* A$.  In other words $|A|^* = |A|$, $\forall v \langle |A| v, v\rangle \ge 0$ and $|A|^2 = A^* A$.

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is a partial isometry, then by definition the operator $U$ is an isometry on   $(\ker U)^\perp={\rm Im}\,U^*$ and $U^*U$ is the projection onto ${\rm Im}\,U^*.$

The condition $UA=|A|$ and the fact that $\|Ax\|=\||A|x\|$ imply that $U$ is an isometry on ${\rm Im}\, A.$ Therefore ${\rm Im}\, A\subset {\rm Im}\,U^*.$  Thus $U^*U(Ax)=Ax.$ Hence $U^*|A|=A.$